# Facebook Login not working on Dev Machine

Tags: facebook, authentication, devserver

I'm running Win Web Server 2008 R2.
I've got a site setup for development which I access on my test machine like this http://bossingway/

I'm trying to put the facebook login on this using their standard code they provide. I haven't added anything.

I've added http://bossingway/ to the SiteURL and it says the URL contains an invalid domain.

I've also tried adding it to Valid OAuth redirect URIs.

I keep getting the Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration error from Facebook.

How do I get it to work on my testing server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the top level domain, if your top level domain is '.com' for example, then you need to add 'http://bossingway.com'